# 7127 code error - Zoho Reports Bulk Import API

Tags: php, curl, report, zoho

I need help. I am getting following error when using Zoho Report Bulk Import API action:

code error 7127 -  100 exceeded maximum length for a column

any solution for this error ?

Type of file to import: CSV
I using cURL with PHP for POST request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

solved. Error in CSV file.

My problem was here:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$objWriter->setDelimiter(','); // here the problem
$objWriter->setEnclosure(''); // here the problem
$objWriter->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
```

The solution:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$objWriter->setDelimiter(';'); // here the change
$objWriter->setEnclosure('"'); // here the change
$objWriter->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
```

regards